# Why does the method of adding goods work incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

When the listener "buttAdd.addEventListener" for the add method is triggered: , first this condition works several times(works with the second addition):

```
if (inputsAdd [0].value ===""||inputsAdd [1].value ===""||inputsAdd [2]
.value === "") 
{alert ("fill all fields");}
```

It works when the fields are not empty, and then the product is added. And if you click on the add button with empty fields, then the product that was added earlier - will be lost. The same story awith the method, delete. Help me please to fix it

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
        this.formAdd = document.forms[0];
        this.inputsAdd = this.formAdd.elements;
        this.buttAdd = this.formAdd.elements[3];
        this.formDelete = document.forms[1];
        this.nameDelete = this.formDelete.elements[0];
        this.buttDelete = this.formDelete.elements[1];

    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    //method for remove product by name
    deleteProductByName(productName) {
        let i = this.products.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // get total price by all products
    get totalProductsPrice() {
        return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    }

    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
        const sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
        });
        this.products = sorted;
    }

    // method to draw the table with product property (
    // name, count, price)
    show() {
        // add new product by click
        this.buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.inputsAdd[0].value === "" || this.inputsAdd[1].value === "" || this.inputsAdd[2].value === "") {
                alert("fill all fields");
            } else {
                this.addProduct(new Product(this.inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(this.inputsAdd[2].value),
                    parseInt(this.inputsAdd[1].value)));
                this.show();
                this.inputsAdd[0].value = "";
                this.inputsAdd[1].value = "";
                this.inputsAdd[2].value = "";
            }
        }, false);
        // delete product by name after click
        this.buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.nameDelete.value === "") {
                alert("write a name of product what you want to delete");
            } else {
                this.deleteProductByName(this.nameDelete.value);
                this.show();
                this.nameDelete.value = "";
            }

        }, false);
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
        const table = document.getElementById("shop");
        const tFoot = table.querySelector('tfoot');
        if (tFoot) tFoot.remove();

        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            //create table
            table.innerHTML += `<tbody><tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr></tbody>`;
        }
        //show total price by all products
        table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td colspan="3" id="total-price">Total price: 
        ${this.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;

//filter products by price
        document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let elem = e.target;
            if (elem.id === "filter") {
                this.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
                this.show();
            }
        }, false);
        console.log(this.products);
    }
}

let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 2, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 3, 1000));
shop.show();
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
    <div class="add-product">
        <h1>Add product</h1>
        <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add" type="button">Add</button><!-- *** -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="product-table">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <form id="delete-form">
            <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
            <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
        </form>
        <table id="shop">
            <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <th id="filter">Price:</th>
                <th>Count:</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"The same story awith the method, delete."* I only see the problem you describe with `add`, not `delete`. (And that makes sense, your `delete` button has `type="button"`, but your `add` button doesn't.) Do you really see it with `delete` in the snippet?

Comment: Yes, the same thing happens with the deletions, I tried the "Run code snippet" in my question

Comment: What's the sequence that makes it happen? I'm doing this: Fill in all three fields and click Add, then click Delete. I get two alerts, but I *don't* get the page disappearing like I do if I click Add without filling in things.

Comment: I sorry, the item does not disappear, only warnings are displayed with each addition or deletion more and more

Comment: Okay, good. That's because of the problem [sychd pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51287269/157247): You're registering your handlers every time `show` is called, so they get added repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, you're defining `let shop = new Shop()` and then use this variable in your Shop class, like `shop.show()`. I strongly recommend you to use `this` keyword instead of scoped variable (valid for all other `shop` usage entries).

Now, about

> works several times

I assume, that when you call the `show()` method it registers more event listeners some time. I mean, you call `show` - it creates new event listeners + sometimes calls itself (huh, it is pretty risky). I suggest you to move listeners declaration to the constructor - so they will be instantinated once (but that will require keeping DOM nodes). Also it would be nice to split your show fucntion to several smaller functions and get rid of self function emit (it will reduce complexity).

Comment: Indeed, using `shop.` within the class makes no sense at all. You might want to add the bit about the default type of `button` elements being `submit`, since that's at least *part* of the problem (and I've deleted my answer that did so, too incomplete).

Comment: @sychd  I changed the code, as you said, moved the announcement of my listeners to the constructor and formatted the method call on the show(). But the problem remained the same